# when not to delete a GTK+ window pointer?

Tags: c++, gtk3

Learning GTK+.  Looking at this (modified) example from the tutorial:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    // create the window and remember it as a simple pointer
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Since `window` is a pointer which is `new`'d in `gtk_window_new()` I figured I would do the right thing and modified it to look like this (note the use of unique_ptr):

```
#include <memory>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    // create the window but this time store it as a smart pointer
    std::unique_ptr<GtkWidget> window(gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL));
    g_signal_connect(window.get(), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_widget_show(window.get());
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

However, this crashes when the managed pointer is deleted:

```
*** Error in `example': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00005620c8cfc510 ***
fish: “example” terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

Valgrind confirms the call to free is the problem:

```
==00:00:00:21.223 17024== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==00:00:00:21.223 17024==    at 0x4C3123B: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==00:00:00:21.223 17024==    by 0x10F240: std::default_delete<_GtkWidget>::operator()(_GtkWidget*) const (/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:78)
==00:00:00:21.223 17024==    by 0x10F6BE: std::unique_ptr<_GtkWidget, std::default_delete<_GtkWidget> >::~unique_ptr() (/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:268)
```

So obviously GTK+ deletes the window itself!?  But does GTK+ manage all pointers itself under the covers?  Or just top-level windows?  Or...?

Note that the documentation for `gtk_window_new()` does not mention object lifetime management, so I'm confused as to the right thing to do with pointers returned from various GTK+ functions. 
 https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-new

---

Edit:  Thinking about this more -- maybe the problem is caused by std::unique_ptr using C++'s `delete` instead of C's `free()`?

Comment: GtkWidget inherits from GOjbect, and GObject does memory management itself.  See https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-memory.html

Comment: Consider using `gtkmm`